# Compare the first word of a page title to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, split, title

the following code gets the page title, compares it with data in array and outputs me a final value

```
var title = (document.title);

//test variables 
testarray =["blue","top","110","in stock", "red","down","111","in stock"]

//function
function testfunction(array, variable){
    var varindex = array.indexOf(variable)
    return array[varindex+2] 
}
//calling the function
testfunction(testarray, title)

var finalvalue = testfunction(testarray, title);
```

So if my page title is Blue, it gives me the value 110 that is what I need. 
It works fine but in this way the only valid title for my page has to be **Blue**, otherwise it won't work.

I would like to be able to have a longer page title like **Blue Shoes** .  I tried by adding the following variable at the beginning to get only the title first word

```
var fulltitle = (document.title);
var title = fulltitle.split(' ').slice(0,1);
```

but it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code ? 
thanks

Comment: Try `title = fulltitle.trim().split(' ')[0]'

Comment: @Francesco you can check my answer as it passes most of the test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues here:

1. When `document.title` is **Blue Shoes** and then you do:

   ```
   fulltitle.split(' ').slice(0,1)
   ```

   It actually returns an array like `["Blue"]`. You need to convert it into text first like:

   ```
   var title = fulltitle.split(' ').slice(0,1)[0];
   ```
2. Also, the `title` value returned is in a different case then what you have in the `testarray` array variable (`"Blue" !== "blue"`), thus `indexOf` doesn't work. You need to make title to lower case like:

   ```
   var varindex = array.indexOf(variable.toLowerCase())
   ```

**Working Demo:**

```js
var fulltitle = "Blue Shoes";
var arr = fulltitle.split(' ').slice(0, 1);
var title = arr && arr.length ? arr[0] : "";

//test variables 
testarray = ["blue", "top", "110", "in stock", "red", "down", "111", "in stock"]

//function
function testfunction(array, variable) {
  var varindex = array.indexOf(variable.toLowerCase())
  return array[varindex + 2]
}

//calling the function
var finalvalue = testfunction(testarray, title);

console.log( finalvalue )
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understand you right, but there can be one problem. Title and value in the array can start from Uppercase or Lower case. try to do something like this.

```
var title = (document.title);

//test variables 
testarray =["blue","top","110","in stock", "red","down","111","in stock"]

//function
function testfunction(array, variable){
    // CHANGES HERE
    var varindex = array.indexOf(variable.toLocaleLowerCase())
    return array[varindex+2] 
}
//calling the function
testfunction(testarray, title)

var finalvalue = testfunction(testarray, title);
```

Answer (score 1):

The test cases in which it succeeds contain words such as `blue`, `blueberry`, `berry blue` in the array. 
Just replace your test function with this

```
function testfunction(array, variable){
   let indexCaptured = '';
   array.forEach((res, index) => {
      if(res.includes(variable)) {
         indexCaptured = array[index+2] 
      }
   });
   return indexCaptured;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `var title = fulltitle.split(' ')[0]`. And bring the compared parts to the same register `var varindex = array.indexOf(variable.toLowerCase())`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `findIndex()` and  `startsWith()`

```js
var title = 'red title';

//test variables 
testarray =["blue","top","110","in stock", "red","down","111","in stock"]

//function
function testfunction(array, variable){
    var varindex = array.findIndex(e => variable.startsWith(e))
    return array[varindex+2] 
}
//calling the function
testfunction(testarray, title)

var finalvalue = testfunction(testarray, title);
console.log(finalvalue)
```